# how to build the simple .net web application using TeamCity?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, teamcity, visual-sourcesafe

I had developed simple .net web application using VS2015. I am new to TeamCity and Microsoft Visual Source Safe (VSS). So, can anyone tell me how to configure VSS and TeamCity, check in the code into VSS from VS2015 and steps for building the simple .net web application using TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main steps 
1) Give your Source control/SVN/VSS path and access details
2) Build Steps

There are multiple options like you can build using solution. or project using MSBuild etc. But that's more of less related to your requirements

Also there is flexiblity to create project and then create child projects. So all your child can use above settings and just override which is required

Comment: Mahesh, can you post some links related to my requirement like configuring VSS and TeamCity in my local machine because I am completely new to TeamCity and VSS.